# ASP.NET Core 3.1 WebRoot Path

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I am pushing an external file into the wwwroot folder of my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. I need to reference the path to provide a constructor variable during the services wire up.

In the Startup class I have added the IWebHostEnvironment to the constructor parameters:

```cs
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  Configuration = configuration;
  _env = env;
}
```

When debugging, it seems that `_env.WebRootPath` returns the path as it is in my source folder, rather than the path being executed, i.e.

It returns:
`<path to my source code>/wwwroot`

Instead of the execution relative path:
`<path to my source code>/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/wwwroot`

How do i get it to return the correct, execution relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because by default the content-root path is the directory where the project is located rather than its output.

If you want to change that behavior, you have to call this line when building the web-host.

`.UseContentRoot(AppContext.BaseDirectory);`

Then the path will change to `<ProjectPath>\Debug\netcoreapp3.1` or whatever you are compiling to.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try something like the following:

```
var rootDir  = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

For further information/help take a glance on this article: [Getting the Root Directory Path for .Net Core Applications](http://codebuckets.com/2017/10/19/getting-the-root-directory-path-for-net-core-applications/)

Comment: While this works great as a workaround (definite upvote and using ;)), it doesn't answer the question as to why the built in method returns the incorrect path. Why is .NET returning the code relative path rather than the executing relative path? I must have made some kind of basic error somewhere - seems inconceivable that this is a bug in .NET Core without 100s of posts showing up on google.

Comment: As it can be seen from the Microsoft's documentation the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-3.1
the WebRootPath Property gets or sets the absolute path to the directory that contains the web-servable application content files, so I don't believe that you are able to retrieve the execution relative path by using the above property.
Thanks for the upvote.

Answer (score 3):

```
private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;

public HomeController(IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
   _env = env;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
   string contentRootPath = _env.ContentRootPath;
   string webRootPath = _env.WebRootPath;
   return Content(contentRootPath + "\n" + webRootPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me

```
string applicationPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
```